# Old Ubuntu Image Won't Boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, kubuntu, btrfs, 19.04

I upgraded to 19.04 a few weeks ago and now I'm trying to downgrade to 18.04 temporarily.

I made backups of my system using btrfs backups to an external drive and then placed my old 18.04 `@` and `@home` directories back on the original drive. They're both labelled appropriately (Not that I forgot to rename them from their backup names) and they're both read-write using
`btrfs property`

I can't get grub to boot it though. I even tried to boot from the grub command line using typical methods, but got stuck when the system mostly booted but I got an additional terminal saying that init wasn't found and I didn't know what to do from there.

I also tried `grub-install` manually setting --boot-directory and --efi-directory but no dice.

I just need to get the system to boot once to recover the encrypted data, so I'm ok if you tell me to just do something at the grub command line to get it to boot. General solutions are fine too though.

This is the screen when I choose default options in grub:
Click image for larger version.  [image: Error]

**EDIT 1:** There is also this error:

```
 kubuntu@kubuntu:/mnt/sdc$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.7G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0  22.4G  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   512M  0 part /mnt/sdc/@/boot/efi
└─sdc2   8:34   0 465.3G  0 part /mnt/sdc
sdd      8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk 
sde      8:64   1  14.9G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sde1   8:65   1   1.8G  0 part 
└─sde2   8:66   1   3.7M  0 part 
sdf      8:80   1   1.9G  0 disk 
└─sdf1   8:81   1   1.9G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1     7M  0 rom  
kubuntu@kubuntu:/mnt/sdc$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=@/boot/ --efi-directory=@/boot/efi/
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
kubuntu@kubuntu:/mnt/sdc$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
```

**EDIT 2:**

I found out that the UUID of the hard drive had changed since I did the install of 19.04, so I changed this in /mnt/sdc2/@/etc/fstab. Strangely, at boot time in grub, it still shows the old UUID in the error prompt. I figured that maybe it was going off an old fstab, so I deleted the boot entries using efibootmgr and then did the grub-install process using --boot-directory and --efidirectory parameters.

Grub-install went fine with no errors, but it still produced the same error at boot time. Still not sure what is up with it. Can't manually boot either.

Here are some pictures of what's happening:
(Manual Boot)
[image: Manual Boot]

(Results of manual boot)
[image: Results]

**fstab:**

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

#Lesser Ark
UUID=8b2f117e-ed70-4405-9524-cac9c249da01    /            btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,compress=lzo,ssd,subvol=@        0    1
#UUID=423F-051C                               /boot/efi    vfat     umask=0077               0    1
UUID=8b2f117e-ed70-4405-9524-cac9c249da01    /home        btrfs    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,compress=zstd,ssd,subvol=@home    0    2
#UUID=45f9fe6b-ae81-47c7-bbd7-f9ca4ac66060    none         swap     sw                       0    0
#UUID=423F-051C    /boot/efi    vfat    defaults    0    1

#ELYSIUM
UUID=0f834b1e-78a4-4b8b-9528-3b6c3f5ae37b /media/sarah/ELYSIUM btrfs defaults,noauto,space_cache,compress=zstd,autodefrag,subvol=EternalFields    0    0

#SENTINEL
UUID=38e88d7b-d527-4784-8060-cfa456c27b13 /media/sarah/SENTINEL btrfs defaults,noauto,space_cache,compress=zstd 0 0

#Convergent Refuge
UUID=bae62e15-46d2-4aa4-84de-5f8bdd93c3e2 /media/sarah/ConvergentRefuge btrfs defaults,noatime,space_cache,compress=zstd 0 0
```

**blkid:**

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:/mnt$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Convergent Refuge" UUID="bae62e15-46d2-4aa4-84de-5f8bdd93c3e2" UUID_SUB="55c809a3-a971-4736-94ef-a11e7f1a6172" TYPE="btrfs" PARTLABEL="Convergent Refuge" PARTUUID="9c3a4912-6cd5-4155-a78f-6356f1acb874"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL_FATBOOT="L_ARK_EFI" LABEL="L_ARK_EFI" UUID="423F-051C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="78554a15-d0ad-4253-870d-2e13f9d5c1d8"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="8b2f117e-ed70-4405-9524-cac9c249da01" UUID_SUB="684c8b61-6133-4e74-a756-314c6c8c5054" TYPE="btrfs" PARTLABEL="Lesser Ark" PARTUUID="611080a8-55e8-4523-9128-bb5cc31c7750"
/dev/sdd: LABEL="SENTINEL" UUID="38e88d7b-d527-4784-8060-cfa456c27b13" UUID_SUB="719dea99-2f2d-4f58-acc1-fd959ca84c14" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="5f43f34d-52f6-4eeb-acd7-8dcc866c752d" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sde1: UUID="2019-04-16-19-25-03-00" LABEL="Kubuntu 19.04 amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="5ed9fb2f" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="5ed9fb2f-01"
/dev/sde2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="039E-EF17" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="5ed9fb2f-02"
/dev/sdf1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="8B27-5FEE" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sr1: UUID="2007-02-13-02-23-10-" LABEL="U3 System" TYPE="iso9660"
```

**Confirmation of Read-Write:**

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:/mnt/chrootdir$ sudo btrfs property get @
ro=false
kubuntu@kubuntu:/mnt/chrootdir$ sudo btrfs property get @home
ro=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parttion tables scares me.

Try to mount your backup using live cd and then chroot into it:

i.e. if /dev/sda1 is your root parititon and /dev/sda2 is your boot parititon:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot # skip it if you don't have separate boot fs
sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Then try to update grub's devicemap and its configuration:

```
grub-mkdevicemap
update-grub2
```

For efi bootloader you may need to reinstall grub-efi:

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
```

In your setup this might be tricky, but maybe https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair would help.

In case of emergency break glass. I mean, install fresh 18.04 from scratch and rsync -av --delete everything except /proc, /sys, /dev and /boot from your backup.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I only /sdc1 and /sdc2 are the actual hard drive. They are the EFI and / partitions prespectivly. Everything else is on my USB hub. ConvergentRefuge is my other internal hard drive and is /sda1. Nothing is on it, it's just a space drive. I'll try your solutions (I already did boot-repair, no luck), but I'll try the binds tomorrow and update the post. I might wind up breaking the glass. Not sure why I can't update grup from the live USB.